# window.print() opens print dialog just on page reload in Chromium v25

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-server

I have a page (actually web app) with defined printable area via `@media print` query.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> combination shows print preview in Chromium v65 and 'print' dialog in Chromium v25. I'm trying to bind 'print' functionality to a button, and invoking `window.print()` inside its click handler. In v65 it opens the same print preview, but in v25 it just does nothing.

The same happens when I'm executing `window.print()` inside browser console.

Can someone guide me what I can check in order to fix this strange behavior?

**UPDATE**

I've just noticed that `window.print()` issued in Chromium v25 console does nothing, but then, after page reload via F5 or via issuing `window.location.reload()` print dialog appears. Thus, it looks like `window.print()` command stuck at execution stack and is pushed for execution just after next command (of the same stack) execution.

NOTE: The web application is Vue-driven application built with webpack.

Comment: This seems to me like a bug on that version. I checked and it works correctly in v37 (earliest version i could find to install). 
Maybe you could try putting it inside async timeout:
setTimeout(function() {
  window.print();
}, 0);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try putting it inside async timeout:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
  window.print(); 
}, 0);
```

Comment: No, this doesn't help. Also, I'm not sure whether it is Chromium bug, because it works as expected if a site is loaded not from webpack-dev-server.

Comment: May I ask why are you concerned with ancient version like that? Chrome has very good auto-update and I am positive that no more than 10 people in whole world are using this exact version...

Comment: That is because Chromium v25 is the target browser. There is no possibility to run newer browser on current client's hardware and OS.